# Postgres complains about missing column when trying to truncate table

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

here's a weird quandry.

I am trying to delete something from my table in code for test purposes. The query it builds is following:

`SELECT syslog;TRUNCATE TABLE syslog;`

This is pretty standard SQL. I also tried `Delete * FROM`

which didn't work either.

My error message:
https://gyazo.com/670c2e95194ca3e40f6cad3bd0ff58ab

Translation: Column "syslog" does not exist.
Why does it even care?

Using Postgres as a database server.

Comment: `SELECT <Tablename>` will give you the error `column "<Tablename>" does not exist` , since you can't select tables.

Comment: Perhaps you intend:  `select * from syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message concerns `select`, not `truncate`:

```
SELECT syslog;
```

Obviously, column `syslog` is not known.